# MMAP segmentation fault

Tags: c, unix, mmap

```
int  fp, page;
char *data;

if(argc > 1){
    printf("Read the docs");
    exit(1);
}

fp = open("log.txt", O_RDONLY); //Opening file to read 
page = getpagesize();
data = mmap(0, page, PROT_READ, 0,fp, 0);

initscr(); // Creating the ncurse screen
clear();
move(0, 0); 
printw("%s", data);
endwin(); //Ends window
fclose(fp); //Closing file 
return 0;
```

Here is my code I keep getting a segmentation fault for some reason.
All my header files have been included so that's not the problem (clearly, because its something to do with memory). Thanks in advance.

Edit: Got it - it wasn't being formatted as a string. and also had to use stat() to get the file info rather than getpagesize()

Comment: Start testing if `fopen` returns a negative value. If yes, that means that the file could not be opened.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would appear that you need to learn how to use a debugger to step line-by-line through your code, which will likely allow you to easily pinpoint the nature and location of the issue you're having. Using a debugger is, for all intents and purposes, required knowledge for any programmer. For more info, see [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @MichaelWalz There's no fopen() in the code. Only open() and that's likely the cause of the crash, when later on calling **f**close().

Comment: @Jens oh yes, I see that now. BTW `fclose(fp);` should at least issue a compiler warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument to `mmap` should not be page size, it should be the size of your file. [Here](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/linux-system-programming/0596009585/ch04s03.html) is a nice example.

Comment: Why? It is perfectly okay and common to only map parts of a file.

Comment: My thinking was that OP is confused about the parameter and mapping past the end of the file. Looks like I am wrong. :)

Comment: But then this can't be the reason for the segmentation fault.

Answer (score 5):

You can't `fclose()` a file descriptor you got from `open()`. You must use `close(fp)` instead. What you do is passing a small `int` that gets treated as a pointer. This causes a segmentation fault.

Note that your choice of identifier naming is unfortunate. Usually `fp` would be a pointer-to-FILE (`FILE*`, as used by the standard IO library), while `fd` would be a file descriptor (a small integer), used by the kernel's IO system calls.

Your compiler should have told you that you pass an `int` where a pointer-to-FILE was expected, or that you use fclose() without a prototype in scope. Did you enable the maximum warning level of your compiler?

Another segfault is possible if the `data` pointer does not point to a NUL (0) terminated string. Does your `log.txt` contain NUL-terminated strings?

You should also check if `mmap()` fails returning `MAP_FAILED`.

Answer (score 3):

Okay so here is the code that got it working

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
int status;
struct stat s;
status = stat(file, &s);

if(status < 0){
    perror("Stat:");
    exit(1);

data = mmap(NULL, s.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
```

Before i was using  'getpagesize();' thanks beej !!!

Comment: Hi Nathan - just to let you know you can mark your own answer as correct if you think it merits it. (see Self-Learner badge)

Answer (score 2):

[mmap's man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) gives you information on the parameters:

> void *mmap(void *addr, size_t length, int prot, int flags, int fd, off_t offset);

As you can see, your second argument *may* be wrong (except you really want to exactly map a part of the file fitting into a single page).

Also: Probably `0` is not a valid flag value? Let's have a look again at the man page:

> The flags argument determines whether updates to the mapping are
>          visible to other processes mapping the same region, and whether
>          updates are carried through to the underlying file.  This behavior is
>          determined by including exactly one of the following values in flags: MAP_SHARED or MAP_PRIVATE

So you could try something like

```
data = mmap(0, size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fp, 0);
```

- **Always** use the provided flags, as the underlying value may differ from machine to machine.
- Also, the mapped area should not be larger than the underlying file. Check the size of `log.txt` beforehand.